# Why doesn't my image and text appear?

Tags: python, pygame

This is my code in question:

```
def game():
     screen.blit(font.render('Choose now!',1,black),(WIDTH/2 - 450 , HEIGHT/2-110))
    
                
     pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event, 0)
                
     ding.play()
                 
     if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                        screen.blit(rock_image,(WIDTH/2 - 450 , HEIGHT/2-110))
                        
        if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                        screen.blit(paper_image,(WIDTH/2 - 450 , HEIGHT/2-110))
                        
        if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                        screen.blit(scissors_image,(WIDTH/2 - 450 , HEIGHT/2-110))
                        
     pygame.display.update()
```

There is a countdown in the game. The idea is that when the countdown ends, the text "choose now!" will appear and you can press either the buttons r, p or s to show an image. However, the text only appears momentarily and pressing the buttons doesn't result in anything either. I believe it may be due to my placement of `pygame.display.update()` but I don't know how to put it in correctly. I've tried placing it under every image upload but it hasn't worked. If anyone wants, this is my entire code:

```
import pygame
import os
from pygame import mixer
FPS = 60
pygame.mixer.init()  
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1000,900
pygame.font.init()
ding=pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join("scissors paper stone folder",'decidemp3-14575.mp3'))
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
white = [255, 255, 255]
black= [0,0,0]
scissors_image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("scissors paper stone folder/scissors-icon-for-web-presentation-logo-infographic-haircut-tailor-hairdresser-haircut-free-vector.jpg"),(100,100))
rock_image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('scissors paper stone folder/images.jpg'),(100,100))
paper_image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('scissors paper stone folder/cHJpdmF0ZS9zdGF0aWMvaW1hZ2VzL3dlYnNpdGUvMjAyMi0xMi9weDExNDM1MzktaW1hZ2Utam9iMTQyN18xLnBuZw.webp'),(100,100))


font = pygame.font.SysFont('Comicsans',30)

counter = 3
text = font.render(str(counter), True, (0, 128, 0))
timer_interval = 1000 

timer_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event , timer_interval)

def game():
     screen.blit(font.render('Choose now!',1,black),(WIDTH/2 - 450 , HEIGHT/2-110))
    
                
     pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event, 0)
                
     ding.play()
                 
     if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                        screen.blit(rock_image,(WIDTH/2 - 450 , HEIGHT/2-110))
                        
        if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                        screen.blit(paper_image,(WIDTH/2 - 450 , HEIGHT/2-110))
                        
        if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                        screen.blit(scissors_image,(WIDTH/2 - 450 , HEIGHT/2-110))
                        
     pygame.display.update()

run = True
while run:
    screen.fill(white)
    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
     if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                break
            
     elif event.type == timer_event:
            counter -= 1
            text = font.render(str(counter), True, (0, 128, 0))
            if counter == 0:
                game()
  
    text_rect = text.get_rect(center = screen.get_rect().center)
    screen.blit(text, text_rect)
    screen.blit(font.render('Hello everyone',1,black),(WIDTH/2 - 450 , HEIGHT/2-290))
    screen.blit(font.render('How about a game of scissors, paper, stone?',1,black),(WIDTH/2 - 450 , HEIGHT/2-250))
    screen.blit(font.render('S button for scissors, p for paper, r(rock) for stone',1,black),(WIDTH/2 - 450 , HEIGHT/2-210))
    screen.blit(font.render('press either of the three once the countdown stops!',1,black),(WIDTH/2 - 450 , HEIGHT/2-160))
    
    pygame.display.update()
```